# Why does JRuby not recognize BigNums while Ruby does?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, bignum

If I type this big integer:

```
puts 9997836544.class.to_s
```

and compile with ruby 1.86, it reports expectedly:

```
BigNum
```

while JRuby (1.1.4 in Netbeans) reports surprisingly:

```
Fixnum
```

I thought Java had a BigInteger class to correspond to the BigNum class in Ruby. If so, I would have expected JRuby and ruby to produce the same output.

Comment: I know Java does indeed have a BigInteger class. But my knowledge about JRuby could fit into a thimble with space left over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this [JRuby bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-1587):

> It seems that JRuby and MRI have different limits to separate Fixnum and Bignum.
>   ...
>   So, MRI uses 0x3fffffff as the biggest FixNum under 32bit environment.
>   And JRuby **always** uses 64bit value: `jruby -e 'p (0x7fffffffffffffff + 1).class'` ---> Bignum.

So try a bigger number and you should get a BigNum as you expect.

Comment: Unbelievable. Thanks for finding this.